# Pythoncard item setsize

Tags: python, wxpython, pythoncard

Below is the base class of my pythoncard application:

```
class MyBackground(model.Background):

    def on_initialize(self, event):
        # if you have any initialization
        # including sizer setup, do it here
        self.setLayout()

    def setLayout(self):
        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)   # main sizer

        for item in self.components.itervalues():
            item.SetSize(item.GetBestSize())
            print item.GetBestSize(),item.GetSize() # here
            sizer1.Add(item, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        sizer1.Fit(self)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer1)
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.visible = 1
```

Which uses the resource file with content below:

```
{'application':{'type':'Application',
      'name':'Template',
'backgrounds': [
{'type':'Background',
      'name':'bgTemplate',
      'title':u'Standard Template with no menus',
      'size': (800, 600),
      'statusBar':1,
      'style':['wx.MINIMIZE_BOX', 'wx.CLOSE_BOX', 'wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX', 'wx.FRAME_SHAPED', 'wx.CAPTION',
               'wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE', 'wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE', 'wx.HW_SCROLLBAR_AUTO'],

     'components': [


 {'backgroundColor': '&H00FFFFFF&',
  'name': 'MinMax0',
  'position': (1080, 9900),
  'size': (732, 220),
  'text': '10000',
  'type': 'TextField'}]}]}
```

On the line that I have marked with a comment saying 'here' prints `(80, 21) (732, 220)` , which i expected to be `(80, 21) (80, 21)`. How can i set the size of the components in a pythoncard application?

Answer (score 0):

Why 80,21?
You told it to make the item 732,220 and that's what it did.

Or is there something else that you didn't tell us?

Comment: I'm sure i've told you everything and anything dear mister, but i don't remember it much since it's been 9 months since i've asked this. anyway, guessing from the question and since it's me, i think i was expecting to see (80, 21) (80, 21) because of setting the size to (80,21) -which is/was the return value of GetBestSize()- by item.SetSize(item.GetBestSize()) in the previous line.
then i hit another problem with pythoncard, if i remember correctly, it was related to scrollbars, and that made me give up and rewrite the application with wxpython from scratch.